# Create directory on SD card root on android 5.1 (lollipop)

Tags: android

Been searching a while on accessing the SD Card root and creating a backup. I also try to use

```
String rawSecondaryStoragesStr = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE");
```

and returning `storage/sdcard/sdcard1` which is the right path. and trying to create a `directory` using

```
try {
                File f = new File(System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE"), "ATTS");
                if (!f.exists()) {
                    boolean isDirectoryCreated = f.exists();
                    if (!isDirectoryCreated) {
                        isDirectoryCreated = f.mkdir();
                        Log.e("success!", "HEY!!!");
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("12", "12");
                }
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

and after checking the log, It logs the "success". but after checking the device explorer, the folder is not created. why is that?.

[image]

and this is my permission on Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="22"/>
```

May I also ask if there is a Runtime Permission on 5.1 that the user needs to accept it. because on the 4.4 or lower. It is automatically accepted without user interactions. Thanks!

EDIT: Add database backup Code

```
private void DBBackup() {
    try {
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        File sd = new File("/storage/sdcard1/ATTS");

        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = "/data/com.jti.mikee.jti_pos/databases/" + DBHelper.DB_NAME;
            String backupDBPath = DBHelper.DB_NAME;
            File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
            File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);

            if (currentDB.exists()) {
                FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
                FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
                dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                src.close();
                dst.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you check f.canWrite() if you can write to it?

Comment: the return is a success. but still the folder haven't created